# Where can I buy Server Type Motherboards with more than 2 Processor Sockets?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit

I'm looking for server type motherboards that have more than 2 processor sockets.

Where can I find these types of boards?

**Edit** - Prefer Intel Xeon based if possible, however, AMD Opteron is ok too.

Comment: Simple answer: In a shop selling them. Check SuperMicro and Tyan for the usual suspects for high quality boards ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to look at manufacturers such as www.tyan.com and www.supermicro.com or even www.intel.com directly [(link for Intel server boards)](http://www.intel.com/cd/products/services/emea/eng/motherboards/server/336442.htm) then typing the model number into either Google or whatever price comparison website you use.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to Newegg you can check the link below, if you look at the description the motherboard you are looking(Intel) for will be listed as having **Dual LGA *****, all .

[Newegg Link](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=302&name=Server-Motherboards)

BTW, I have purchased before from Newegg before without any problem.

Comment: aren't those dual socket motherboards?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has mentioned Newegg, so I'll add another vendor: [www.provantage.com](http://www.provantage.com) has a wide array of server boards both Xeon and Opteron.

You could try using Google's product search [www.froogle.com](http://www.froogle.com) and use [www.resellerratings.com](http://www.resellerratings.com) to get some history on the vendors themselves.

Keep in mind, quad core boards *typically* aren't suited to fit full ATX cases. They're usually customized for that vendor's case products (Supermicro and Tyan come to mind).

Comment: Quad boards are commonly Extended ATX, which is hard to find in a normal chassis (some server chassis are). The 8 processor boards all require a custom case (the ones I've seen anyway).

Comment: I've seen most Quad (CPU) boards in SSI/CEB form factor, not E-ATX. Unless SSI/CEB is synonymous with E-ATX, I don't *think* it's possible to fit 4 or more CPUs on an E-ATX sized board or at the very least, it's *very rare* to see quad cpu boards in an E-ATX form factor.

Answer (score 0):

try your luck at http://newegg.com - they have some [quad-socket motherboards](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010200302+1071330126&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&Subcategory=302&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=). probably you'll be buying tyan / supermicro / intel server platforms.

Comment: Thank pQd.  Do you happen to know of any that accept the Intel Xeon series processors?  All of the ones on newegg take AMD's Opteron.

Comment: you can find some older quad-socket motherboards for intel cpus at http://supermicro.com/products/motherboard/matrix/index.cfm . you can google for shops that sell it. if that does not satisfy you - i'm afraid you'll have to go for ready-built server like dell r900.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you really do these days. Such motherboards are usually sold as a complete product like HP DL500 - as the form factor required to fit this isn't exactly a consumer specification.

If Intels dual-socket Skulltrail requires Extended ATX and Asus recently announced the first dual-socket current-generation Intel motherboard that fits into ATX - a quad-socket variant in those form factors seems unlikely even though AMD versions in SWTX exists.

Here're [some examples of Supermicro boards](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon7000/#7500) though, they're listed as having a "Proprietary" form factor with custom chassis available ^^